# JSON String to ListView not happening

Tags: android, json

I have a JSON String, I am trying to parse and then into ListView, my code does not throw any errors but it is not working either, I am unable to determine where I might be going wrong. Following is my code:

```
      protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            str = result;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // Able to toast the JSON string (str) here. 
            mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            try {
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(str);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);


                        j_id = jObject.getString(ID);

                        j_make = jObject.getString(MAKE);

                        j_model = jObject.getString(MODEL);

                        j_version = jObject.getString(VERSION);
                        j_price = jObject.getString(PRICE);
                        j_reg_plc = jObject.getString(PLACE_REG);


                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"After assign", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                    data = "Make: "+ j_make + "\nModel: " + j_model + "\nVersion: " + j_version + "\nPrice: " + j_price
                            + "\nCity: " + j_reg_plc;



                    map.put("car", data); 

                    mylist.add(map); 

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }




    //  list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+mylist, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        String[] from = new String[] { "car"};
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text1 };
        ListAdapter adapt = new SimpleAdapter(view_cars.this, mylist,R.layout.text_adaptr, from, to);

        list.setAdapter(adapt);


    }
```

It seems that my for loop is ubruptly exiting, It is not getting executed twice as the length of the array I am recieving from network is two. I have attached the screen shot of the JSON Array I am getting [image]

Please check the code for comments, for detailed information.

Comment: you have commented the listview initialization.are you aware of that.

Comment: Try to trace your code to see where it goes wrong.

Comment: it doesn't throw any errors because you catch 'em ... check logcat anyway ... there is an error in your code - you should move `map = new HashMap<String, String>();` into "for" loop - whitout this modification you will end with all rows == last row ...

Comment: Yes I have initialized it globally.

Comment: Lemme check with moving it inside the for loop!

Comment: Its still not working, I get an empty array in myList, on executing: Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+mylist, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: The Log Cat does not give me any hint too Ill post a screen shot.

Comment: @Egor I am using toast messages to trace the code, they are excuted only once, however they should run twice as the array length is two. Somewhere something is going wrong inside the loop. I am able to print  a toast after **JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);** but I am not able to print a toast after **j_id = jObject.getString(ID);**

Comment: if you getting "After assign" toast then it should work ... maybe `text_adaptr.xml` is wrong ...

Comment: But then I should get values in myList, whereas I toast it and get a **[]**

Comment: hashmap obj create inside of for loop. for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

HashMap<String,String>  map = new HashMap<String, String>();
mylist.add(map);
}

Comment: i too facing this problem. i need to post user details with image, when i post png image it works when jpg image its shows toast like this without error.

Comment: Guys I have got the error, it was a silly mistake I had referenced a wrong variable. Thank you very much for the valuable guidance.